# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error because: 1'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error because 1'

while trying to call a stored procedure from SQL.

I've also tried to change how I call the procedure but still with the same error

Here's my code:

```cs
SqlConnection Connect = new SqlConnection(Connection);
SqlCommand ProCommand = new SqlCommand("persons", Connect);

ProCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Person", personName);
ProCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Connect.Open();
ProCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SQL:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Persons(@PersonType NVARCHAR (256))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRY
        SET @info = 'SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK''' +@PersonType+ ''', 
      SINGLE_CLOB) as j';

        CREATE TABLE #tempTable (tempdata varchar (max));
        INSERT INTO #tempTable
        EXEC (@info);

        DECLARE @Temp VARCHAR(max);
        SELECT @Temp= tempdata FROM #tempTable;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            EXECUTE per.Group
        COMMIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        INSERT INTO main.[errorLog] ([Number],[Message], [Procedure], 
    [LineNumber], [Severity], [State])
        VALUES (ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 
    ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE());

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(45);
        SET @ErrorMessage = 'This error occured becuase ' + 
    CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NVARCHAR(32));

        THROW 50001, @ErrorMessage, 16;
    END CATCH;
END;
GO
```

Comment: And what does your stored procedure look like?

Comment: Post your stored procedure.

Comment: That's not a SQL Server error message. Post the *full* exception, including any inner exceptions and the call stack. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: You'll need to open up the black box and find out what the stored procedure called `persons` is doing (assuming that that actually is a stored procedure, otherwise you're definitely doing it wrong). That error looks like a classic case of someone implementing their own error handling with custom messages (`RAISERROR`).

Comment: I edited my code

Comment: Dig deeper -- now you need to know what `per.Group` is doing. (Also, that code is almost certainly broken -- it's not syntactically valid since `@PersonType` lacks a `@`, `Group` isn't quoted when it has to be since it's a keyword *and* the parameter isn't even used. Post actual code, not an impression.)

Comment: Posted actual code..

Comment: Well there you go -- that code will produce the unhelpful and misspelled `This error occured becuase 1` to indicate that `main.ErrorLog` now contains the *actual* error. `per.Group` may do something similar. Try `SELECT * FROM main.ErrorLog WHERE ID = 1` for more insight. (The `ID` may have a different name; it's the column with the identity in any case.) You may get *nothing* if the error was of the kind that doomed the transaction, preventing further inserts -- this is not the most reliable way of doing error handling.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks that was really helpful!!

Comment: The lesson from this appears to be not to generate custom error messages which don't provide useful information. Hiding error details is sensible in the public facing layer of an app (e.g. UI or public API) so that sensitive information doesn't leak outside the environment, but I can't see much reason to do it at the database level. Just let the actual error bubble up instead